# How can I use LinearLayout two times with different postions ? center and bottom

Tags: java, android, layout

[image]

I wanna to add one button in the center, and two in the bottom (one on the lift and the second on the right) using linearlayout programmatically if that possible ?

best practice and different idea are welcome too

A picture attached, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Center Button" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Left Bottom" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Right Bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you opened my eyes to something called layout weight !!

Comment: One more thing, is that possible to make left button on the left and right button on the right instead both of them in center ?

Comment: just solved the part two of my question using RelativeLayout for both bottom buttons, Thanks again

Comment: Its possible with LinearLayout too but Relative will be shorter and better.